# knex always returns the same results from query

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

trying to make a search feature that will search database and return any results 'like' a string. when I call database using SQL it is working okay, but when I try to call with knex I get either 0 results or it is the same results no matter what I change the string to.

sql (working)

```
 SELECT * FROM stockList WHERE symbol LIKE '%AAPL%' AND sec_type = 'stock';
```

I am using req.params to with a route to call a knex function. the 2 things that can be changed are the 'sec_type' and 'symbol'

Route

```
    app.get('/api/getStockList/:nameType/:queryParams', requireLogin, async (req, res, next) => {

        const {nameType, queryParams} = req.params;
        
        //Call Search Function 
        const searchData = await Search.searchSymbols(nameType, queryParams);
        res.send(searchData)
    })
```

knex function

```
//Connect to Database
const knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'admin',
    password: keys.MysqlPassword,
    database: 'csv_stock_data',
  },
});

//Create knex function
exports.searchSymbols = async (search = '', sec_type) => {
  console.log(search + sec_type)

  //If No type selected Default is All
  if (sec_type === 'All') {
    const results = await knex('stockList')
        .select({
            symbol: 'symbol',
            displaySymbol: 'displaySymbol',
            description: 'description',
            sec_type: 'sec_type',
        })
        .where('symbol', 'like', `%${search.toUpperCase()}%`)
        // .orWhere('description', 'like', `%${search}%`);
        console.log(results)
    return results.map((row) => {
        return row;
      });
  } else {
    //else return data by type
    const results = await knex('stockList')
        .select({
            symbol: 'symbol',
            displaySymbol: 'displaySymbol',
            description: 'description',
            sec_type: 'sec_type',
        })
        .where('sec_type', sec_type)
        .where('symbol', 'like', `%${search.toUpperCase()}%`)
        // .orWhere('description', 'like', `%${search.toUpperCase()}%`);
    return results.map((row) => {
        return row;
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Run your app with `DEBUG=knex:*` environment vatiable set and you will see if the sent query is actually what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Given your desired SQL statement, I can get there with something like:

```
knex('stockList')
    .select()
    .where('symbol', 'like', `%${'foobar'.toUpperCase()}%`)
    .where('sec_type', 'stock')
```

Which produces the statement:

```
select * from "stockList" where "symbol" like '%FOOBAR%' and "sec_type" = 'stock'
```

You can experiment with this exact query here: [QueryLab](https://michaelavila.com/knex-querylab/?query=NYOwpgHgFA5AzgFwPYGNgBkCWiYEoBQABMScQHRxgA2YKCUBppZA7gBZgBOYscAngFsARkiowANIRhVMwMBMIADAKQASAN4wAZkiRCAhpxhlkAVQAO5rgGF9lBgF9lixk3LsuPeLQD6CPlYK8MhoeEA)

You'll need to put your `variable` back in there, I put the `'foobar'` string for testing.